# Ionic popover not hiding second time

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic version "1.1.0" and angular version "1.4.3"

I am facing issues with Ionic popover, I have created ionic popover out of html template, popover is opened based on user action, i have two buttons on the popup, and in the button handler i am writing code =>$scope.popover.hide() to close the popover, It works fine for the first time, it closes, Second time again when the popup is opened its not getting closed

need your advice and wanted to know if i am missing something

and on hide method promise, i am doing the state transition, second time when we click on the popover buttons, state transition is happening but popover is not getting closed

below is the code snippet i am using

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('app/layout/eo-confirmation-popup.html', {
                    scope: $scope,
                    backdropClickToClose: false
                }).then(function (popover) {
                    $scope.dataLossPopover = popover;
                       $scope.dataLossPopover.show(angular.element(document.querySelector('.popupPosition')));
                });
```

and on click of button calling below code

```
$scope.dataLossPopover.hide().then(function () {
            $state.go(...);
        });
```

Thanks,
Mallik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('app/layout/eo-confirmation-popup.html', {
                    scope: $scope,
                    backdropClickToClose: false
                }).then(function (popover) {
                    $scope.dataLossPopover = popover;
                });


$scope.openPopover = function(event) {
    $scope.dataLossPopover.show(event)
}
$scope.closePopover = function(event) {
    $scope.dataLossPopover.hide(event).then({
        $state.go();
    })
}
```

If you are opening popup on click

```
<button ng-click="openPopover($event)"></button>
<button ng-click="closePopover($event)"></button>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above approach, its not working, the issue is when i click on the close popover button, $scope.dataLossPopover.hide() method is getting executed and control comes to promise of hide method but by this time ideally popover should be hidden but in my case its not getting hidden and code in the hide method promise section is getting executed which is resulting in state transistion, and the popup remains on the screen.

Comment: please check, you are doing wrong somewhere, try as shown in my code. Write show method out of the popover definition

Comment: Thanks Its working now after moving show method out of the popover definition